# stripping an url from a text

Tags: php, regex, url

How do I get to strip a url and put it back in the same position?

Answer (score 6):

Use regular expressions.. you can easily detect the URL using regexs.

[Detecting a URL](http://www.regexguru.com/2008/11/detecting-urls-in-a-block-of-text/)

[Replacing a Pattern](http://www.webcheatsheet.com/php/regular_expressions.php)

Comment: I read that, it just says detecting, my question is extracting and replacing it back in the same position.

Answer (score 1):

There are not many ways to regexp an url that is compliant with rfc3986

As a C string, the regex will be:

```
"^(([^:/?#]+):)?(//([^/?#]*)|///)?([^?#]*)(\\?[^#]*)?(#.*)?"
enum {
    URL = 0,
    SCHEME_CLN = 1,
    SCHEME  = 2,
    DSLASH_AUTH = 3,
    AUTHORITY = 4,
    PATH    = 5,
    QUERY   = 6,
    FRAGMENT = 7
};
```

Where the enum denotes what capture indexes correspond to which url parts.

Answer (score 0):

If you're wanting to put the same URL back into its initial position, why do you want to remove it in the first place/ what exactly are you trying to do. A little more context would help us help you.

Comment: supposing the url is http://yahoo.com I need to reformat it as <a href="http://www.yahoo.com">Yahoo</a>

Answer (score 0):

you're probably looking for [`preg_replace_callback`](http://www.php.net. /preg_replace_callback).

it simply matches a regular expression pattern, gives the result to a function you provide, and replaces the original match with its return value.

Answer (score 0):

Jeff Atwood had an [informative post](https://blog.codinghorror.com/the-problem-with-urls/) regarding the issues you might face with this.

Regardless of the programming language and libraries you use, you will have problems with some cases, e.g., --http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/archives/001181.html-- when using a straightforward regex substitution.

I don't use PHP very often, but the issue boils down to trying to figure out the pattern to use in the [preg_replace](https://php.net/preg_replace) call.

Comment: The link to Jeff's article is purposely adjacent to -- to highlight the difficulty of determining where a URL ends when link detection is done automatically. To access the article, remove the two dashes from the end of the URL.