# How can I convert URLs in text to HTML links?

Tags: html, perl, url

I'm writing a forum-type discussion board in Perl and would like to change automatically http://www.google.com to be an HTML link.  This should also be safe, and err on the side of security. Is there a quick, easy, and safe way to add links automatically?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
use Regexp::Common qw /URI/;

$text =~ s|($RE{URI}{HTTP})(?!</a>)|<a href="$1">$1</a>|g
```

The key here is using Regexp::Common::URI which probably has a more thorough url matcher than anything I could come up with.  Also I do a [negative lookahead assertion](http://www.perl.com/doc/manual/html/pod/perlre.html) at the end to make sure that the url is not already in a link.  That last part isn't exactly thorough, since it's possible that somebody could do something like this:

```
<a href="http://www.mysite.com">http://www.mysite.com is my website</a>
```

To do this correctly you'd need to parse the entire submission text and only substitute out urls that are not already part of a link.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/819144/stripping-an-url-from-a-text/819972#819972